# Pick<Foo, Bar> & Omit<Foo, Bar> !== Foo in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm running into an error where:

```
Pick<Foo, Bar> & Omit<Foo, Bar> !== Foo
```

This is confusing to me b/c I expect that Pick should select those keys in Bar, and Omit should select those keys not in Bar, however when I try this in TypeScript I run into an error:

```
export function bind<
  TOpts extends Record<string, unknown>,
  TReturn,
  TBound extends keyof TOpts
>(
  fn: (opts: TOpts) => TReturn,
  bound: Pick<TOpts, TBound>
): (opts: Omit<TOpts, TBound>) => TReturn {
  return (opts) => {
    return fn({
      ...bound,
      ...opts,
    });
  };
}

Argument of type 'Pick<TOpts, TBound> & Omit<TOpts, TBound>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TOpts'.
  'Pick<TOpts, TBound> & Omit<TOpts, TBound>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TOpts', but 'TOpts' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, unknown>'.
```

TypeScript playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwEaYoAmAPAFBxwAqA8mDAM5ygzDFMBKwa0pDMUQgHMANHFQBrFBADuKAHwiK1LjCRQUSylQBCEVEWYhW7OBOABPCAmp1GZeQAplCFAC44jiPQYfaPgEo4AF55FWA1DS18fWIPAAVMNAkSf0YxXViieTIAjy8fDxoAW0wYVLsGDL0DeSDQ8MjcAG9lKAj1XALGerDWykp2psQUR36BygA6abws6Inpye905UoAXwCAbmU17bWyIA

My question is is that error justified or just an aberration of one of TypeScript's optimizations? Specifically, what value of TOpts and TBound would cause that not to be true?

Comment: It's a design limitation (or perhaps missing feature), see [ms/TS#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884). The compiler doesn't perform the sort of higher-order reasoning needed to verify equivalence here.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? If you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me.

Comment: @jcalz yup! Feel free to write up and I'll approve

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Comment: When typing a signature takes longer than implementing and testing it. Go TS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known missing feature of TypeScript, described at [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884):

> The core problem is that an intersection of complementary subsets of a higher order type, constructed using `Pick<T, K>` or by other means, is not assignable back to that higher order type. ...  If and when we implement the improvement suggested by this issue the ... assertion ... becomes unnecessary.

So generally speaking `Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>` should be assignable to `T` but the compiler can't see it.

(Well, there are some edge cases where it wouldn't be assignable. For example, if `T` has a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) like `{(): string; a: number}` then, the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `Pick` and `Omit` would both be lacking the call signature; see [microsoft/TypeScript#27575](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27575).  But I'm not worried about those edge case too much here.)

Anyone who wants to see this logic implemented might go to the GitHub issue linked above and give it a  so that the TS team can gauge the level of community interest.  Currently it doesn't look like it will be implemented anytime soon, and I doubt a few upvotes will change that.  But it wouldn't hurt.

Until and unless this feature is implemented, you should probably use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler you know what you're doing:

```
return fn({
  ...bound,
  ...opts,
} as TOpts); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwEaYoAmAPAFBxwAqA8mDAM5ygzDFMBKwa0pDMUQgHMANHFQBrFBADuKAHwiK1LjCRQUSylQBCEVEWYhW7OBOABPCAmp1GZeQAplCFAC44jiPQYfaPgEo4AF55FWA1DS18fWIPAAVMNAkSf0YxXViieTIAjy8fDxoAW0wYVLsGDL0DeSDQ8MjcAG9lKAj1XALGerDWykp2psQUR36BygA6abws6Inpye905UoAXzgAQyY0hgCAbjgAeiO4CAlNi2U1-bI1siA)