# TypeScript: how to make a generic defaulting function using generics and subtypes?

Tags: typescript, generics

Given two interfaces

```js
// the "normal" state
interface State {
    index: number;
    offset: number;
}

// let's extend it with some additional fields
interface SpecialState extends State {
    search: string;
    filter: string;
}
```

I'm trying to create a function that would take as argument a partial object of type SpecialState, which *must* include the extended properties, and optionally any property from the base type. The input type would thus be something along these lines

```js
type InitialState<T extends State> = Partial<State> & Omit<T, keyof State>;
```

This works fine, I can create an object where `search` and `filter` are required, and `limit` and `offset` are optional.

```js
const initialSpecialState: InitialState<SpecialState> = {
    search: 'hello',
    filter: 'bonjour',
    index: 2
};
```

The result of the function would be a complete object of the extended type (in this case SpecialState). I.e. the function would "know" about the base interface, and be able to produce default values for those properties in case they're missing from the input. But it cannot produce any default values for the extended properties, since they're unknown. Hence, they need to be given in the input.

Thus, this function would be generic and take any extension of the base type `State` as type argument.

```js
function makeFinalState<T extends State>(initialState: InitialState<T>): T {
    const baseState: State = {
        index: 0,
        offset: 0,
    }

    // TS doesn't like this
    const mergedState: T = {
        ...baseState,
        ...initialState
    }

    return mergedState
};
```

This is where TypeScript throws an error at me

```
'{ index: number; offset: number; } & Partial<State> & Omit<T, keyof State>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'State'
```

However, the function works fine for my use case regardless of the error

```js
const finalState = makeFinalState<SpecialState>(initialSpecialState);
console.log(finalState)
// logs 
// {
//   "index": 2,
//   "offset": 0,
//   "search": "hello",
//   "filter": "bonjour"
// }
```

So what's wrong here? Or should I go about this in a totally different way?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsFNQIgHYHsBOBbAhgGzqAzuBuNAFACWCxKAZhgMawDKhxoA3iaF6BQCbQAPAFygEAVzQAjaCgDcnbkmrU80cCPFSZ8gL4kSIUFjUByPKEHEEvHuFAB3MlHxI0sDL15OySBNlDUZNBYvHjklDK0DKCMAA7QdGTYzESwltDW5imsHNz40BgodJAiBCgUAObyeYFYVKXg5QhVJHoGYCjQAI5iZJ08CN7%20BKkQSKCQGABu7lhYoO0WAlb8NrEoSPEo4EHmFKAAKqAY1qCbO77YWACeZ1Ay5tQbaDEspODX8aAAkoM7yW8ADxHdKZV6pAB8oAAvKAAAqFf5YQHZaBQgBkoAA8mgnMCADSgADW0GuSnBxAh8kW9lQRLwpQKRUgx1OtSox36kiQzk6PT60F4%20MWfEErJsShUajOsQufiwJDovgIAyGWDiCSS6reIl%20atRKPiiQBkJh7AUXFUhWKIhMMDmSBMwpqZDqMlt3IQACskGIUE6LQN%20MJQAAmVrUwwYWKxLC7CAwVVI-BvM4IMaxM7UY6gSQYVQp1KLdZIXhiRLNVlnSRehJ2ckfL4HEjUMQIOhy0CYEkAMQoJuIwKWKyybwhAAoKPqdT8-lqDQcIQBKERHXLcJUIFV51SokSos3rvJcUUhgAMzuPXElqnUoAvgbaeUMB0YoF4SGgeAQJjscZJeSBpuKpuCgFSCnuhyHoGeQAHTwTu0CopeV7wbBU5Iqij76HknTgH66ageBvBYTokZgLSKD0iI9wBP28wjKwZDmF6YgqvYkx2N8SxGsQvCKsqdiBPKB6wt20B9iJQIasa2qQpOc7JEa85vEu1LAUgxiwVgSAVOOwkDtAS4kEAA)

Comment: TypeScript can't perform arbitrary reasoning about generic conditional types, unfortunately.  You can rewrite it to [this form](https://tsplay.dev/w6QXvW) which satisfies the compiler and gives types equivalent to what you want.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You got me on the right track! But is the FinalState really necessary? I was able to work around it by just returning State & T. [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPMxzw)

Comment: It’s not necessary, it’s just personal preference how you represent equivalent types.  I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeScript type checker is not sophisticated enough to reason abstractly about [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `InitialState<T>` inside the body of `makeFinalState()`.  (The [`Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is implemented with a conditional type, and `T` is generic.)  It would be great if it could recognize that `Pick<T, keyof State> & Omit<T, keyof State>` would be equivalent to `T`, but that's beyond its capabilities at the moment.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) and [Pick<Foo, Bar> & Omit<Foo, Bar> !== Foo in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74306198/2887218) for more about that.

So you'll have a better time if you refactor your types so that it doesn't require such understanding.  Here's one possible approach:

```
function makeFinalState<T extends Partial<State>>(initialState: T) {
    const baseState: State = {
        index: 0, offset: 0,
    }
    const mergedState = { ...baseState, ...initialState };
    return mergedState
};
```

The compiler infers that the result of the spread is an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the spread types, meaning that you get something like `State & T`.  This is equivalent to what you want:

```
const finalState = makeFinalState(initialSpecialState);
// const finalState: 
//  { index: number; offset: number; } & Partial<State> & Omit<SpecialState, keyof State>
```

Of course that type is somewhat ugly, and contains an unnecessary `Partial<State>` in there, but it works.

---

Depending on your preferences you can get a simpler type output:  we can make an "identity" [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that just maps a type to itself, to prompt the compiler to evaluate the type instead of leaving it as an intersection:

```
function makeFinalState<T extends Partial<State>>(initialState: T) {
    const baseState: State = {
        index: 0, offset: 0,
    }
    type Id<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } & {}
    const mergedState: Id<State & T> =
        { ...baseState, ...initialState }
    return mergedState
};
```

That results in the following output type:

```
const finalState = makeFinalState(initialSpecialState);
/* const finalState: {
    index: number;
    offset: number;
    search: string;
    filter: string;
} */
```

which is possibly nicer... again, depending on your preferences.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAUMg5UAEwgA8AuZEAVwFsAjaAbn0IHsYYBnCMK2oxa4AvrlyhIsRClQAHCAmBwANukwpykEMW5oMWPIWS84UBAAsq3MFFABzVsZjAVU67YesxuMAE8FZABJEGAwZTUDCAAeABVkLQgdPXVIAD5kAF5kAAUzcNVo1IgMgDJkAHk6MLiAGmQAawg-Tn0NNNYEdhAbIlCCtQUlVWKqELCI4qKhyaiM7KNCU3MrZAByCwgVFXY12rYCFzdoKjWGboArdhooPYO+0kpkACZRVlwYGhAEcO7kOjgTQAYqARlE4gkyNpdLl8hEinM0gAKUATMEaKixACUOHuXR6YGQDDgvFGbSwC3uxhI5CoAAZ6pweHx6ftjGJjP5AkFiHF5jhkABtADSfUazVasQAupiRVLkCJkOVsBzCPjenRoPYIMQyTyERolchYvMqYRsMgAHTW4mkqL1a2W1EDYoK+5QPg3ED-LU64pvcTqwkuEDoin-QEQEGhyIaFH9SYzMMQLGsAD0ACpkEHkCHk1RFgQaU9BEwoE4OFxePxqPQyxWCMtLB47CBHPcju4TJ4295kBm0+JcOr2CoIJadvYkXnY5AsbggA)

Comment: Very well explained!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript cannot infer this:

```
    // TS just cannot prove this 
    const mergedState: T = {
        //~~~~~~~~~~~ Error TS2322
        ...{} as Pick<T, keyof State>,
        ...{} as Omit<T, keyof State>
    }
```

so you have to cast it

```
    const mergedState: T = {
        ...baseState,
        ...initialState
    } as T
```

Comment: Casting is certainly one way of working around it. I tend to avoid it, though.